# c++ template member function with partial spezialisation outside class

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

this code use a template member that work different for std::vector and other types. So far it works fine. But what is the correct syntax to define the get methode for std::vector outside the class ? i am aware about using traits and other helpers to make this working but i would like this simple solutions if there is an valid syntax.

`#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct s
{
  template < class X > void get (X x)
  { 
      cout << "inner\n";
  };
  
  template <class X> void get(std::vector<X> vec)
  {
      cout << "inline any vector\n";
  }

};

int main ()
{
  std::vector < int >vec;
  std::vector< double> dvec;
  s x;
  x.get (1);
  x.get (vec);
  x.get(dvec);
  return 0;
}`

this seems not to work

`template <class X> void s::get(std::vector<X> v) 
{
}`

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the correct syntax to define the get methode for std::vector outside the class ?

That would be to just declare it in the class template and then go ahead and define it outside:

```
struct s {
    template < class X > 
    void get (X x) { 
        cout << "inner\n";
    }

    template <class X>            // declaration
    void get(std::vector<X> v);
};

template <class X>                // definition
void s::get(std::vector<X> v) {}
```

Comment: This is right but for a function like template <> void::get(int) you can define it completely outside without mentioning it inside the class. With the std::vector not

Comment: @Markus I'm not sure I get it completely. Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/c139a5) what you want to have?

Comment: Thx for the sample but this still declares the special get inside the class. Think about an external user who wants to add a new „get“ function for std::set ... so in your sample i have to add all possible calls inside the struct „c“

Comment: @Markus Ok, I think it's starting to sink in. Sorry, I have a fever :) Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to make a partial specialization for any `std::vector` from `template<class X> void get(X x);`